# Telegram answerInlineQuery can't parse number

Tags: c#, json, telegram, telegram-bot

I am working on a bot with new feature of Telegram bot API called InlineQuery, i implement all types in C# and now can get the query returned from Telegram to my bot, when i try to answer the query i post below Json to Telegram answerInlineQuery method but i get this error :

"Bad request: Can't parse json encoded inline query results: [Error]: can't parse number"

```
{"inline_query_id":"515050766530700016","results":[{"type":"photo","photo_url":"http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/car/car-05.jpg","photo_width":0,"photo_height":0,"description":"wrdqw","caption":"wer","id":"46156165165","title":"123","message_text":"123","parse_mode":"Markdown","thumb_url":"http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/car/car-05.jpg","disable_web_page_preview":false}],"cache_time":300,"is_personal":false,"next_offset":"0"}
```

This is my structure of AnswerInlineQuery according to this documentation : https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answerinlinequery

```
public class AnswerInlineQuery
{
    public string InlineQueryId { get; set; }
    public List<InlineQueryResult> Results { get; set; }
    public int CacheTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsPersonal { get; set; }
    public string NextOffset { get; set; }
}
```

and "InlineQueryResult" :

```
public class InlineQueryResult
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    public string ParseMode { get; set; }
    public string ThumbUrl { get; set; }
    public bool DisableWebPagePreview { get; set; }
}
```

and "InlineQueryResultPhoto" :

```
public class InlineQueryResultPhoto : InlineQueryResult
{
    public string Type => "photo";
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
    public int PhotoWidth { get; set; }
    public int PhotoHeight { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

I try to pass empty results like this :

```
Bot.AnswerInlineQuery(new AnswerInlineQuery
{
    InlineQueryId = inlinequery.Id,
    Results = new List<InlineQueryResult>(),
    IsPersonal = false,
    CacheTime = 300,
    NextOffset = "0"
});
```

But again i get same error, it seems the problem is not in "results" !

I don't know which number it means and tryout the Json with many different data but i can't fix it, is my structure of Json wrong ? any idea ?

Thanks .

Comment: Also, can you show your classes corresponding to [`answerInlineQuery`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inline-mode) and [`InlineQueryResultPhoto`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultphoto), and how you are serializing to JSON?

Answer (score 3):

The problem solved , result parameter must be string variable contain Json array of result not exactly the Json array :

```
results = new RestRequest().JsonSerializer.Serialize(answer.Results)
```